# Accessing UserControl control in another window

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have a `UserControl` that contains a `ListView` and a `Button`. I have included my `UserControl` in `Window1.xaml`, but I don't know what do I have to do so I can access my `ListView` control in `Window1.xaml.cs` .

What else should I need to do ? What is the best aproach here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not something you should be doing, instead create properties on the UserControl which the internals are bound to, then you have a clean interface.

e.g.

```xml
<UserControl Name="control" ...>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, ElementName=control}">
        <!-- ... -->
```

```cs
public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(MyUserControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

```xml
<Window ...>
    <local:MyUserControl x:Name="myUc"/>
        <!-- ... -->
```

```cs
myUc.ItemsSource = new string[] { "Lorem", "Ipsum" };
```